# Fastest way of updating items of one list from another using StartsWith

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, ienumerable

I have a scenario where I need to update few items based on the data from another list. I have already gone through various questions over here but none helped.

Scenario

listA: Total Count around 88000

```
public class CDRs
 {
    public string cld { get; set; }
    public string prefix2 { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
 }
```

listB: Total Count : 3000.

```
public class RatesVM
    {
        public string prefix { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
```

Now in **listB** there can be multiple matches of **listA** field that is **cld**

for eg.
listA.cld = "8801123232";
Matched prefixes from ListB I get is

```
880     BGD Proper
8801    BGD Mobile
88011   BGD Dhaka Mobile
88017   BGD Dhaka Mobile
88018   BGD Dhaka Mobile
88019   BGD Dhaka Mobile
```

Now I want the closest match in this case it would be

```
88011   BGD Dhaka Mobile
```

Approach I am following right now.

```
foreach (var x in listA)
            {
                var tempObj = listB.FirstOrDefault(y => x.cld.StartsWith(y.prefix));
                if (tempObj != null)
                {
                    x.prefix2 = tempObj.prefix;
                    x.country = tempObj.Country;
                    x.city = tempObj.City;
                }
                else
                {
                    x.prefix2 = "InBound";
                    x.country = "Unknown";
                    x.city = "Unknown";
                }
            }
```

It works fine but takes a lot of time. **Around 2-3 minutes** for this case.

There are few scenarios where ListA will have around 1 million records. I am worried it will take forever.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to find closest matches at all? Why you can't link them directly? Also, you mention `Contains` in the title but you haven't shown the code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I went with the assumption that they meant StartsWith and edit the title for em :P

Comment: A bit faster would be, if you split your List to the number of Cores you have on your computer and use the Parallel.Foreach() Method.
 --> [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx) <--

Comment: Did any of those options work for you @JitenderSharma ?

Comment: @mjwills - Indeed, yours is the fastest one here, and after that answer of Tim-Schmelter works well for some scenarios as well, But when I have like 2 million records its getting slow which is usual as per my requirement. So I decided to avoid this and have stored the data just like I needed in sql only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the below code. The key difference is using `orderedListB` to ensure that you get the most specific match possible (i.e. start with the longest prefixes first), as well as a `Dictionary` to cache results. *

```
Dictionary<string, RatesVM> cache = new Dictionary<string, RatesVM>();
var orderedListB = listB.OrderByDescending(z => z.prefix.Length).ToList();

foreach (var x in listA)
{
    RatesVM cached;
    cache.TryGetValue(x.cld, out cached);
    var tempObj = cached ?? orderedListB.FirstOrDefault(z => x.cld.StartsWith(z.prefix));

    if (tempObj != null)
    {
        if (cached == null)
        {
            cache.Add(x.cld, tempObj);
        }

        x.prefix2 = tempObj.prefix;
        x.country = tempObj.Country;
        x.city = tempObj.City;
    }
    else
    {
        x.prefix2 = "InBound";
        x.country = "Unknown";
        x.city = "Unknown";
    }
}
```

*You may also want to consider using `Parallel.ForEach` rather than just foreach.*

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is hard, because you need the 'closest' solution rather than any solution at all. This forces you to iterate of every record in `listB`, for each element in `listA`.

Since you need an answer for every element in `listA` you are forced to check every element in it.

You can however preprocess `listB` by creating a *tree structure*. You create a node for each different first number of all strings in B. Then that node will be the parent of all records in `listB` that start with that number. The nodes below that node will hold the second number in the string, and so on.

Went ahead and drew you a visual idea of what such a tree might look like:

[image]

Now if you search in `listB`, you don't have to iterate over the entire `listB` but can just traverse down the list which will increase your time per iteration from `O(n)` to `O(log n)`.

You would take the first letter in a record in `listA` and compare it to the tree, and traverse in that branch (instantly eliminating a huge amount of records you otherwise would need to compare against, increasing your performance). Then compare the second letter, etc untill no more letters can be found in the tree. When you stop, you have found the longest matching record in `listB` guaranteeing the 'closest' match, which `FirstOrDefault(\x -> x.StartsWith())` doesn't do at all! (It finds the first match only, which is almost always just the first letter!).

You only have to create this tree once for all searches in `listA`, and if there are changes in `listB` you can easily update the tree as well.

If you're running this on a decent machine with more than one core, you can also parallelize this search. It increases the complexity of the program you're writing because you need to manage which thread searches which record in `listA` though it will help out greatly with the performance and will greatly lower the amount of time needed.